# RouteCollection get routes not working in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

I was tried to get routes by using this code block

```
public function routeSave(RouteCollection $routes){
   $routeCollection = $routes->getRoutes();
   dd($routes);
 }
```

but it returns this on web browser

```
 RouteCollection {#556 ▼
 #routes: []
 #allRoutes: []
 #nameList: []
 #actionList: []
 }
```

then how can i get the result correctly ?

Comment: Where do you call this function

Comment: in routes ```Route::get('routes', 'HomeController@routeSave')->name('routes');```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

public function routeSave(){
   $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
   dd($routeCollection);
}
```

Update to answer to comment:

```
$routeNames = [];
foreach ($routeCollection as $route){
  $routeNames[] = $route->getName();
}
```

Comment: thank you @Kerel, can you explain how to extract only nameList array from output.

Comment: ```@Kerel``` is it possible to get only index actions from getAction method ?